# How do I enable HDMI output on Nvidia GTX 650?

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

I just built new PC:

- AMD 8350 CPU
- ASUS sabertooth motherboard
- Nvidia GTX 650 graphics card
- Ubuntu 12.10

System boots fine and desktop is fine using VGA connection, but there is no HDMI video output to the monitor (HP w2207h) using the Nouveau drivers.

Tried a second other type of monitor with HDMI and had the same thing "NO SIGNAL".

So I used "System Settings" and changed from Nouveau driver to NVIDIA Proprietary but still have "NO SIGNAL" from the HDMI port. On both monitors I did press the on screen menu to attempt to switch the HDMI port but on both they just time out and display "NO SIGNAL" and return me to the VGA input.

I did put a call on Sunday to PNY (the brand of GTX 650 card I bought) to ask them for any possible solution.

I'd appreciate any suggestions about how to troubleshoot this further to understand why and how to enable the HDMI port's video output to either of these two monitors.

Comment: What version of the Nvidia drivers did you install? And did you try to use the "Nvidia Settings" application or the regular Display Settings application?

Answer (score 3):

### Are the correct drivers installed?

First of all, check that you actually have the correct nvidia drivers installed (this will check whether they are installed and install them if they aren't already):

Fire up a terminal, and then:

- If you want the stable (tested, but old) drivers, do:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

- If you want the latest (possibly untested, but fresh from nVidia) drivers, do:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`

---

Once you're done with that, restart your computer to check that the drivers are working correctly (check the bottom of the post if they aren't).

Now, shut down your computer (or just shut down the X server(s)), and then remove the VGA cable. Then, plug in the HDMI cable.

Now start up your computer. Is it working?

If not, check that the monitors you have work with another HDMI output (ie: X360, PS3, DVD Player, etc.). If they don't, it might just be your monitors.

If the monitors work but the card isn't working, it may be a defect with the card, or an alternate setup may be required.

---

### If the (newly installed) drivers weren't working:

Hit `Ctrl + Alt + F1`

You will be shown a terminal. Log in using your username and password.

Stop whatever display manager you're using:

- LightDM (Default): `sudo service lightdm stop`
- GDM (GNOME): `sudo service gdm stop`
- KDM (KDE Plasma Workspaces): `sudo service kdm stop`
- Any other display manager (custom/other desktop environments): `sudo service [display manager name] stop`

---

Then, uninstall the nvidia drivers:

`sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current nvidia-current-updates`

Once this is finished, reinstall the nvidia drivers as shown at the top of the post.

Restart the computer:

`sudo reboot now`

---

### Did it work out in the end?

If all of the above doesn't solve the problem, tell us what didn't work.
If it did work, mark the solution, and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an Nvidia Geforce 600 Series card, please go here [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/which-driver-should-i-install-when-using-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card)

The solution as I wrote there is using either the 313 or 319 drivers (Recommend using the 319 which came out yesterday). Basically the part you need to read (I actually recommend reading the whole guide I made) is this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

This would add the Xorg Edgers PPA to your system.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This would update the system and make sure your system knows of the packages provided by the added PPA.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This would update the system taking into consideration any packages the PPA offers.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-319
```

That should leave you with the latest version of Nvidia and with support for the 600 Series cards.